# Is it possible to have both positional and named CLI options using optparse-generic?

Tags: haskell

I'd like to make a CLI using the Haskell library optparse-generic. The [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-generic-1.3.1/docs/Options-Generic.html) shows an example for positional arguments, and another for options (e.g. `--flag=True`), but I can't figure out how to combine the two. I've tried something like this:

```hs
data CLI = CLI Options Files deriving (Generic, Show)

data Files = Files [String] deriving (Generic, Show)

data Options = Options { colorMap :: String <?> "Color mapping to use."
                       } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance ParseRecord CLI
```

But that doesn't seem to be legal.

Comment: What's the error? Is it compile-time or runtime?